# How to find text in table based on another text using xPath

Tags: xpath

I have a table with columns and rows when the row cell of interest has the following XPath:

```
//table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/b/a
```

The cell contains the text `ABC`

I can only use the following XPath:

```
//table[2]//b[text() = 'ABC']
```

I would like to find the name of the column header responding to that row cell. The correct XPath is

//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th[2]

The difference is coming in `/td` and `/th`. Can I somehow return the position of the first XPath and use it inside the second? Like:    //table[2]//b[text() = 'ABC']

```
//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th[ //table[2]//b[text() = 'ABC']position() ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
//table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th[position() = count(ancestor::tbody/tr[2]/td[b/a='ABC']/preceding-sibling::td) + 1]/text()
```